# 2017 Healthcare Data on Primary Care Service Areas, Availability of Primary Care Providers

Tags: data-request, geospatial, medical

I will start by saying I am interested in answering a few specific questions namely:

1. Number of Primary Care Providers per 10,000 persons
2. Percentage of areas with Low Primary Care Physician Supply (Low being defined as <= 3,500 residents per doctor).
3. Number of Federally Qualified Health Center sites per 10,000 persons
4. Number of FQHC sites per square land mile

I found this interesting dataset which divides the United States into Primary Care Service areas (PCSA) which was designed to provide more accurate mapping procedures to illustrate how groups or populations of people made use of medical resources.

https://datawarehouse.hrsa.gov/data/datadownload/pcsa2010Download.aspx

The following download files contain the relevant information I need to answer my questions.

- PCSA v3.1 Layer Attributes (File 1)
- PCSA v3.1 Layer Attributes (File 2)
- HRSA National Primary Care Physician Inventory Data

Unfortunately, this data is a bit old since as it's from 2010. I was curious if anyone knew of any updated datasets using this unique Primary Care Service Area designation.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a dataset which could answer my questions at some different geographic level? Ideally it would be at least the county level.